# Send mail using Nodejs with HTML body

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, nodemailer, template-strings

I am trying to send email from my server using nodemailer. Unfortuantely, I have been unabe to test it due to this error:

```
D:\Full Stack\Node\NodeLoginJWT\functions\password.js:58
        'This token is valid only within two minutes.'
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Full Stack\Node\NodeLoginJWT\routes.js:9:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the code block causing the error:

```
const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport(`smtps://${config.email}:${config.password}@smtp.gmail.com`);

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `"${conifg.name}" <${config.email}>`,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Reset Password',
    html: `Hello ${user.name}`, 

        'Your account password token is ${random}'
        'This token is valid only within two minutes.'

        'Thanks,'
        'Team. '
  };

  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

Comment: which is line no 56

Comment: Just below the html line, starts from -  'Ýour account... '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem in your interpolation .

```
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `"${conifg.name}" <${config.email}>`,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Reset Password',
    html: `Hello ${user.name}, // the tick should not come here 

        'Your account password token is ${random}'
        'This token is valid only within two minutes.'

        'Thanks,'
        'Team. '` // the tick should come here
  };
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using Nodemailer and here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

router.post('/', handleSendEmail); // handle the route at yourdomain.com/sayHello

function handleSendEmail(req, res) {
    // Not the movie transporter!
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'Gmail',
     auth: {
         user: '', // Your email id
         pass: ‘’// Your password
     }
    });
    var text = 'Hello from \n\n' + req.body.user_name;
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'sender@gmail.com', // sender address
        to: 'receiver@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Appointment Email Example', // Subject line
        text: text,
        html: '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
        '<html><head><title>Appointment</title>'+
        '</head><body><div>'+
        '<img src="http://evokebeautysalon1.herokuapp.com/main/img/logo.png" alt="" width="160">'+
        '<p>Thank you for your appointment.</p>'+
        '<p>Here is summery:</p>'+
        '<p>Name: James Falcon</p>'+
        '<p>Date: Feb 2, 2017</p>'+
        '<p>Package: Hair Cut </p>'+
        '<p>Arrival time: 4:30 PM</p>'+
        '</div></body></html>'
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.json({yo: 'error'});
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            res.json({yo: info.response});
        };
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is more elegant but problem has been solved. Thanks